# Change keyboard's keycodes

Tags: keyboard, dvorak

As far as I understand it, when you push a key on a keyboard, it sends a keycode to the computer, and from there further processing occurs.

I'm a Dvorak typer, and have to use my bosses computers a lot, and I don't want to bother him with any software switching of the keyboards.

Is there a way for me to get into the usb receiver and change the keycodes that my keyboard sends? I'm using a [Logi T540 keyboard](https://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/k540-wireless-keyboard).